# R names() not seeing all variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe 'prog' and I want to change the names of the variables. I can view 'prog' and see that as expected it has 3 variables, but when I try to rename these using 'names()' I get an error message saying that I have to match the number of arguments to the length of 'prog' which it claims is 2. I'm quite new to R and assume that I am creating 'prog' in a bad way, but I don't see exactly how.

```
prog <- 
  pro %>%
  group_by(totexp_rng) %>%
  summarize(sqrt(var(food_t))*1.2816)
prog <-
  prog %>%
  mutate(
    totexp_rng = pro %>%
    group_by(totexp_rng) %>%
    summarize(mean(food_t))
  )
names(prog) <- c("totexp_rng","mean","to90")
```

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag and note in particular that sample code should be complete and self contained including all ibrary statements and inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are saving a dataframe/tibble in `totexp_rng`. This is not a usual way to code using `dplyr`.

You should always name your variables in `summarise`/`mutate` calls which will avoid the need to rename the variables later. Also, you can apply more than one function in `summarise`/`mutate`  so you can simplify your code to -

```
library(dplyr)

prog <- pro %>%
  group_by(totexp_rng) %>%
  summarize(to90 = sqrt(var(food_t))*1.2816, 
            totexp_rng = mean(food_t))
```